# {Is/are + adjective} or {have been+ adjective}?

Tags: grammar, difference, verbs, adjectives

When to use {have been + adjective} as both sentences look the same.

Can anyone explain when to use 'have been' and when to use only 'is/are'?

> 1. You **have been** *dishonest* to me.
> 2. You **are** *dishonest* to me.

Comment: It is more natural to say "...dishonest **with** me.

Comment: 'to' is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

"You **have been** dishonest to me." is in the *present perfect* tense, which is used to describe something that happened in the past, but the exact time it happened is not important. It has a relationship with the present. ([ecenglish.com](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/how-use-present-perfect))

"You **are** dishonest to me." is in the *present simple* tense, which describes the current situation.

You can also use "have been" and verb, for example:

> "I have been eating"

...which means I have been eating for some time including now. This is the perfect simple continuous tense. You can see more examples [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21918/294113).

Comment: I know the difference between simple present and the perfect one but sometimes we say like 'it has been' I want to know can we use this for any incident that just has happened. Like do you know we are in love with each other. I know it 'has been' and it will be.

Comment: "Have been" is typically used for the past events (let's say "remote" events) in which the time is not defined or important. In your particular case "have been dishonest" doesn't sound right for something what just happened, so you use "are." "Has been and will be" is very commonly used. You can use it for the case in your comment: It means that we have been in love (for some time) and we always will be.

Comment: So I can say have/has/had been in sentences like this also. I told him don't be dupe by someone. Sorry to say but he had been.

Comment: Yes, probably. I would need to read a complete sentence to say, though.

Comment: My actual question is when to use have/has/had+been. What is the criteria for that. Should we use only in verb 'be' situations. Like in this sentence 'he should be a champion don't worry he has already been in his mind'.

Comment: You can also use "have been" with other verbs, for example "I have been eating." I made an example in my answer.

Comment: I know the perfect continuous tenses. But I want to know only 'have/has/had+been' uses. When to use this pattern.

Comment: Can you edit your original question to show what exactly do you need to know? I guess, you want to ask what are criteria for using "have been"...but please explain this in your original question

Comment: I'm just asking can we use has/have/had +been for something that has/had happened. Or should we use this only in conditions where verb need the participal form of verb 'be'?

Comment: Yes, you can use "have been" for something what happened, like "I have been playing music."  So you can _add_ the verb after "have been." You can also replace "been" with a verb, like "I have played music." If this does not answer you, please make your own example of a sentence.

Comment: Like in this sentence also 'Did you remember we had a dinner that night? Yes it had been.

Comment: The answer to the question: "Did you remember we had a dinner that night?" can be "Yes, I remember," but not "Yes it had been." If the question has a real verb (remember), then the answer also has to have this verb (remember) and not "been." If the question is "Have you been in cinema?" then the answer can be "Yes, I have been." OK now?

Comment: This sentence like 'have you been attacked by them. Yes I have been. Attacked (past participal) is also a  real verb here.

Comment: Oh, OK. Yes, you can say just "Yes, I have been." "Have been attacked" is in present perfect" with "attacked" in passive voice.